# Create Before Insert Trigger in oracle and implement in asp.net web form

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

I have a requirement of which I want to create a `trigger` in Oracle.

So what I want is: I have a table called `XXCUS.XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_TRL` in which there is a column called `ACTION` whose default value is set as `RELEASE`, `EXTEND` and `CANCEL`.

So my trigger would be on the table `XXCUS.XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_TRL` as

whenever the column `ACTION` has values as

1. `RELEASE` then the other table column should get UPDATED as `R` with the same matching `ID`
2. `EXTEND` then the other table column should get UPDATED as `O` with the same matching `ID`
3. `CANCEL` then the other table column should get UPDATED as `C` with the same matching `ID`

The other table name is `xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all` whose column needs to be updated. Also the column name is `CLOSE_FLAG`.

I m trying like below

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_T
BEFORE INSERT
  ON XXCUS.XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_TRL
  [FOR EACH ROW]
 DECLARE
   -- variable declaration
 BEGIN
   -- trigger code
  Insert into XXCUS.XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_TRL -- values for ACTION here
   then 
  update xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all if 'RELEASE' then 'R', if 'EXTEND' then  'O' where mkey = dynamic
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
  -- exception handling
  END;
```

but it is not working as I am not champ in creating `Triggers`. Kindly help me with this

Comment: 'it is not working' What's not working?

Comment: @sagi: the trigger which I created is not working and giving error as `ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command`. I am newbie to triggers. If possible guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: you don't need square brackes (`[`, `]`) in the statements.

Comment: If you remove the square brackets ' [ OR REPLACE ] -> OR REPLACE ' and in the FOR EACH ,still the same error?

Comment: @sagi, sathya: after removing `[` and `]` i get error as `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While going through the links and documentation, I tried my self and figured out the solution.

There were many syntax errors in the starting. But I guess, I was the only one to apply the exact logic and took help of the syntax online.

So here it was my `TRIGGER` which I wrote and it worked perfectly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER xxcus.xxacl_pn_prospect_trl_trg
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON xxcus.xxacl_pn_prospect_trl
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
 sql_error   VARCHAR (10000);
  v_mkey      NUMBER;
  v_action    VARCHAR (10);
BEGIN
   v_action := :NEW.action;
    IF (v_action = 'Extend')
      THEN
  UPDATE xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all
     SET no_of_days = :NEW.current_action_days
   WHERE lease_num = :NEW.lease_no;               
  ELSIF (v_action = 'Release')
THEN
    UPDATE xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all
     SET no_of_days = 0,
         close_flag = 'R'
   WHERE lease_num = :NEW.lease_no;               
    ELSE
      UPDATE xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all
       SET no_of_days = 0,
         close_flag = 'C'
   WHERE lease_num = :NEW.lease_no;               
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
  sql_error := SQLERRM;   END;/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious syntax errors

- You don't need square brackets. Those are in the documentation to indicate optional parts.
- Your insert/update statements are wrong, need to correct them.

It should look on the lines of :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_T
BEFORE INSERT
  ON XXCUS.XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_TRL

 DECLARE
   -- variable declaration
 BEGIN

     UPDATE xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all
     SET CLOSE_FLAG = DECODE(:NEW.ACTION, 'RELEASE','R','EXTEND','O', 'CANCEL','C') 
     WHERE ID = :NEW.ID

END;
```

This trigger will update CLOSE_FLAG column of xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all based on what value comes in Action column of XXACL_PN_PROSPECT_TRL table.

Comment: hi sathya, thanks for the answer. I finally created a trigger which is as per my requirement. Now need to use it in my code. have a look at the updated question